# How to find and replace a attribute in the txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that has contents as follows:

```
#-------------------- INPUT --------------------
# file name- This is input file name
-input_file
2
/home/useser/file_in1.txt
/home/useser/file_in2.txt
# Output file- this is output file
-output_file
2
/home/useser/file_out1.txt
/home/useser/file_out2.txt
```

Now, I want to replace the `/home/useser/file_in1.txt` by `/home/useser/file_in3.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in2.txt` by `/home/useser/file_in4.txt` in the field `-input_file`. Same process must be happen in the field `-output_file`. I am using python 2.7 and this is what I tried. But I cannot achieve the expected result as

```
#-------------------- INPUT --------------------
# file name- This is input file name
-input_file
2
/home/useser/file_in3.txt
/home/useser/file_in4.txt
# Output file- this is output file
-output_file
2
/home/useser/file_out3.txt
/home/useser/file_out4.txt
```

My python code is

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file_3='/home/useser/file_in3.txt'
    input_file_4 = '/home/useser/file_in4.txt'
    out_file_3='/home/useser/file_out3.txt'
    out_file_4 = '/home/useser/file_out4.txt'
    f = open('input.txt', 'r')
    for line in f:
        if '-input_file' in line:
            print line
```

How could I do? Thanks

Comment: Of course you cannot achieve it: you aren't even trying to as your code only prints some stuff, but doesn't attempt to change the file's contents. Please show your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `str.startwith()` and `str.replace()` functions:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:  # open file in read/write mode
    lines = iter(f.read().splitlines())  # cobverting list to iterator
    f.seek(0)  # reseting file pointer
    for l in lines:
        if l.startswith('-input_file'):
            num = next(lines)
            in1 = next(lines).replace('file_in1.txt', 'file_in3.txt')
            in2 = next(lines).replace('file_in2.txt', 'file_in4.txt')
            f.write('\n'.join([l, num, in1, in2]) + '\n')
        elif l.startswith('-output_file'):
            num = next(lines)
            out1 = next(lines).replace('file_out1.txt', 'file_out3.txt')
            out2 = next(lines).replace('file_out2.txt', 'file_out4.txt')
            f.write('\n'.join([l, num, out1, out2]) + '\n')
        else:
            f.write(l + '\n')

        f.truncate()
```

The new `input.txt` contents:

```
#-------------------- INPUT --------------------
# file name- This is input file name
-input_file
2
/home/useser/file_in3.txt
/home/useser/file_in4.txt
# Output file- this is output file
-output_file
2
/home/useser/file_out3.txt
/home/useser/file_out4.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well. One more thing that I want to ask is that I want to write the `/home/useser/file_in3.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in4.txt` based on the `-input_file`, instead of using  `/home/useser/file_in1.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in2.txt` as condition. Could you help me also?

Comment: @KimHee, is the file's format static, is there always only 3 lines followed by `-input_file` or `-output_file`?

Comment: Yes, it is static. After `-input_file` will be number `2` and then two file paths. Same as `output_file`. In additions, you did not save it in the `lines.txt`. Please update the write it to file also.

Comment: Sorry, I have check again. Although it worked as expected, it has a minor mistake. I do not want to use replace funtion. I just want to write `/home/useser/file_in3.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in4.txt` in the position of `/home/useser/file_in1.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in2.txt`. On other hands, with two new input as `/home/useser/file_in3.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in4.txt`, it will write to field `-input` without any conditions like comparison with  `/home/useser/file_in1.txt`. Sorry for my English that make you misunderstood

Comment: Because of in real case, I do not know the `/home/useser/file_in1.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in2.txt`. Hence, with two inputs, my expected will write to field `-input_file` at the positions of `/home/useser/file_in1.txt` and `/home/useser/file_in2.txt`. Thanks

Comment: How do you think the code as `content=next(lines) 
 content.replace(content,'/home/useser/file_in3.txt')`? because I do not know the content of `/home/useser/file_in1.txt`, so I just replace the content of next line by '/home/useser/file_in3.txt'

Comment: @KimHee, It's not good of you to change conditions on the fly. I've made a working solution for your current input